# changing a list of lists and makind a new one in python 2.7

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list like this small example:

```
mylist = [['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']]
```

I am trying to make a new list of lists in which instead of every sublist, I would have 3 sublists. in fact the `new list of list` (called newmylist) would have 6 sublists.
in fact in the newmylist every 3 new sublists are similar expect for columns 3 and 4. column 3 is start and column 4 is end. to calculate columns 3 and 4 in the newmylist, I would divide the `(difference between columns 4 and 3) by 3`. 
for example regarding regarding the 1st `sublist` in `mylist`:

```
(14409 - 11873)/3 = 845
```

so in the 1st sublist in newmylisy, start is 11873 and end is 12718 and in the 2nd sublist start is 12718 and end is 13563. also in the 3rd sublist start is 13563 and end is 14409. the 2nd 3 sublists in newmylist will be made from the 2nd sublist from mylist. here is the expected output

`expected output`:

```
newmylist = [['chr1', '+', '11873', '12718', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '+', '12718', '13563', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '+', '13563', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '15162', 'WASH7P'], ['chr1', '-', '15162', '15963', 'WASH7P'], ['chr1', '-', '15963', '16765', 'WASH7P']]
```

I am trying to do that in `python` using the following code. this code does not return what I am looking for. do you know how to fix it?

```
start = []
for item in mylist:
    start.append(item[2])

end = []
for item in mylist:
    end.append(item[3])

diff = []
for item in mylist:
    d = item[3]-item[2]/3
    diff.append(d)

newmylist = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    content = [i[0], i[1], start[i], start[i]+diff[i], i[4]]
    newmylist.append(content)
```

Comment: Please fix your post so its not as hard to read. Remove the code blocks throughout that are just supposed to be text.

Comment: @kstullich I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really splitting your list into 3 separate ones (in your last loop). One way to do this is to define a function called `split` that splits your list like you want. Then you can call that function on each sub-list conveniently:

```
def split(l, chunks=3):
    diff = (int(l[3]) - int(l[2])) // chunks
    res = []
    for i in range(chunks):
        res.append([l[0], l[1], str(int(l[2]) + diff * i), str(int(l[2]) + diff * (i + 1)), l[4]])
    res[-1][3] = l[3] # adjust last number to match what "l" has
    return res    

mylist = [['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']]
newmylist = []
for lst in mylist:
    for newlst in split(lst):
        newmylist.append(newlst)

print(newmylist)
```

**Output**

```
[['chr1', '+', '11873', '12718', 'DDX11L1'],
 ['chr1', '+', '12718', '13563', 'DDX11L1'],
 ['chr1', '+', '13563', '14409', 'DDX11L1'],
 ['chr1', '-', '14361', '15162', 'WASH7P'],
 ['chr1', '-', '15162', '15963', 'WASH7P'],
 ['chr1', '-', '15963', '16765', 'WASH7P']]
```

Note that you can also use a list comprehension if you prefer that:

```
newmylst = [newlst for lst in mylist for newlst in split(lst)]
```

Comment: how can I make the split function more general. for example if instead of 3 I want to use 1000, I can not do that manually like split. how can I make it more general?

Comment: @elly You can use a `for` loop with the right calculations based on the chunk size (see updated answer).